# Sql query for times do not fit

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem to understanding how these SQL queries work properly for the times.

I have inserted the following database entries:

```
ID | Name   | start    | ende     | jahr | tag | monat | beschreibung
1  | python | 19:33:00 | 19:33:35 | 2017 | 18  | 7     | etwas
2  | python | 19:34:35 | 19:36:35 | 2017 | 18  | 7     | etwas
3  | python | 19:37:35 | 19:38:35 | 2017 | 18  | 7     | etwas
4  | c_c++  | 20:38:35 | 20:39:35 | 2017 | 18  | 7     | etwas
5  | python | 21:37:35 | 21:38:35 | 2017 | 18  | 7     | etwas
6  | c_c++  | 21:39:35 | 21:40:35 | 2017 | 18  | 7     | etwas
```

If I now ask the whole of the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT name, tag, jahr, monat, min(start) as min_start, max(ende) as max_ende,
                    SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( ende - start ) ) as gesamtzeit,
                    SEC_TO_TIME( SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(ende)) - SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(start))) as arbeitszeit,
                    SEC_TO_TIME( SUM(ende - start) - (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(ende)) - SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(start))) ) as pause,
                    GROUP_CONCAT(beschreibung) as besch
        FROM lernen
        WHERE monat = $monat_1 AND jahr = $jahr_1
        GROUP BY name";
$db_erg = mysql_query( $sql ); if ( ! $db_erg ) { die('Ungültige Abfrage: ' . mysql_error()); }
```

I get the following result:

```
Tag | Monat | Jahr | von      | bis      | Gesamtzeit | Arbeitszeit | Pause    | Name   | Beschreibung
18  | 7     | 2017 | 20:38:35 | 21:40:35 | 00:03:20   | 00:02:00    | 00:01:20 | c_c++  | etwas
18  | 7     | 2017 | 19:33:00 | 21:38:35 | 00:07:15   | 00:04:35    | 00:02:40 | python | etwas
```

I do not understand the following. How is the total time and the time of pausing now composed? How can I enable this so that I can only count the pause time between ID 1 - 4 + ID 5 - 6 for python and for c_c ++ from ID 4 - 5?
For an idea as I can calculate the end - start correctly would be really grateful.
thx and lg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution:

```
$sql = "
       select name,
       DATE_FORMAT(start, '%d.%m.%Y') as datum,
       min(DATE_FORMAT(start, '%H:%i:%s')) AS start,
       max(DATE_FORMAT(ende, '%H:%i:%s')) AS ende,
       (select SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, min(start), max(ende))) from zeiten ) as ges_zeit,
       SEC_TO_TIME(sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, start, ende)) ) as arbeitszeit,
       SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, start, ende) ) as diff_2,
       SEC_TO_TIME(sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, start, ende)) ) as diff_1,
       SEC_TO_TIME((select TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, min(start), max(ende)) from zeiten ) - (select sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, start, ende) ) from zeiten)) as diff,
       beschreibung as besch
       FROM zeiten
       WHERE DATE_FORMAT(start, '%m') = $monat_1 AND DATE_FORMAT(start, '%Y') = $jahr_1
       group by start
       order by DATE_FORMAT(start, '%d %H') DESC
       ";
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to solve this with a simple query. For these reasons:

- You are calculating monthly totals which means that the `min_start` and the `max_ende` time for each `name` would be the first and last time of the month an entry for this `name` was logged. So the calculated `pause` would include all the breaks between days too. AS the time you sleep is not generally counted towards `pause`, you'd have to group by day in a subquery. This would give you daily `min_start` and `max_ende` which you could aggregate further.
- When calculating the `pause` time, you need to define on how interleaved entries of different `name` are calculated. If I log `12-13 python` and `14-15 c_c++`, will the hour between 13 and 14 count towards `python` or `c_c++`? Or both? You will need another subquery that aggregates the `pause` time  according to that rule.

So the answer is that you have to find out how to calculate `pause` and then prepare the right data in subqueries before doing the monthly aggregation.

Comment: Ty for the Inspiration of subqueries! i will try to do that and if it works i will post it to.

Comment: sry, but could you give me plz an other tip? i cant realize why this query give me SEC_TO_TIME( (select max(start) from lernen where ende > 0 )) as time_1, give me 59:25:35 as result! I have just 1 day and i cant figure out how it Looks like with the combination to get that value.

Comment: `max(start)` is already in time format, so don't try to convert it with  `SEC_TO_TIME()`. In your case the string '21:39:35' is converted to the decimal number 213935 before being interpreted as seconds! 213935 seconds is a bit over 59 hours which is why you get that nonsensical result.